# Cannot access external IP Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I have a VM instance installed with Jira Software with port 8080. The service is up and running. But I cannot access the external ip with 8080 port. GCP ingress Firewall set to allow 0.0.0.0/0 to all ports/protocols. Tried to allow HTTP on the instance setting but still cannot access the external IP.

Please Advise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are somethings you can check. Following the steps that you can check and troubleshoot:

1. You need a Firewall Rule to allow traffic from the VM port (Seems this has already done).
2. The VM should have an [external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) and a service listening on the desired port.  (Seems this has already done too).
3. In case Jira uses a container, the container must have an IP and port opened.

Outsider connections will follow this path:

1. Web Browser >> http://host-ip:8080
2. GCP project firewall
3. Instance port 8080
4. Container port 80s
5. Succesfull connection!

Meaning that 80 is the container's port and 8080 is the port mapped on the host VM in GCP.